How to remove seeds constraint in my solana program built with anchor?
I am currently a beginner in Solana development and following a tutorial by https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/anchor/create-tokens.
pub fn init_token(ctx: Context<InitToken>, metadata: InitTokenParams) -> Result<()> {
    let seeds = &["mint".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];
    let signer = [&seeds[..]];

    let token_data: DataV2 = DataV2 {
        name: metadata.name,
        symbol: metadata.symbol,
        uri: metadata.uri,
        seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
        creators: None,
        collection: None,
        uses: None,
    };

    let metadata_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            update_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        },
        &signer
    );

    create_metadata_accounts_v3(
        metadata_ctx,
        token_data,
        false,
        true,
        None,
    )?;

    msg!("Token mint created successfully.");

    Ok(())
}

And the context for this InitToken function is defined as :
 #[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: InitTokenParams)]
pub struct InitToken<'info> {
    /// CHECK: New Metaplex Account being created
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"mint"],
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = params.decimals,
        mint::authority = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metaplex>,
}

The tutorial explained that by adding a seeds constraint seeds = [b"mint"] it forces the program to be able to create a single mint account. But what if I want my program to be able to create multiple mint accounts, one for each newly created token, how do I modify the code? Is it possible to have dynamic seeds on the client-side and remove the seeds constraint from the program?
Thanks

This will create the mint account as a PDA(off-curve address). To change it, use an on-curve address for convenience(using a PDA will only allow you to generate one mint account using "mint" seed or force you to keep changing the seeds).
Change your mint account initialization to not include the seeds and bump
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = params.decimals,
        mint::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

Here is an Accounts struct I did before with the repo link shared below.
pub struct CreateToken<'info> {
    #[account(mut, address = ADMIN_ADDRESS)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = args.decimals,
        mint::authority = payer.key(),
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MetadataAccount::find_pda(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    pub metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    /// CHECK:
    pub sysvar_instruction: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

You'll use const mint = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate(); on the TS client side to generate the accounts, then sign with this newly created KP
const txHash = await program.methods
            .create(args)
            .accounts({
                payer: anchor.AnchorProvider.env().wallet.publicKey,
                mint: mint.publicKey,
                metadataAccount: findMetadataAddress(mint.publicKey),
                metadataProgram: METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                sysvarInstruction: SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY,
            })
            .signers([mint]) // important
            .rpc({ skipPreflight: true });

Check out the full code base on this spl token minter repo

"Force you to keep changing the seeds" true, but one account per mint, with a deterministically discoverable address, may be what OP prefers. It might be worth adding an example for that option too!

Thank you for this @mikemaccana. If you need the mint managed by your program, check out this answer https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/14843/1708
